# Is it possible to join 2 lines of logs from 2 separate log files using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a 2 separate `IIS` log files (advanced and simple)

They need to be joined, because the advanced log is missing information that the simple one has written, but they have the same timestamp.

```
input { file {
    path => "C:/Logs/*.log"
    start_position => "beginning"}
}
filter {
    grok {
        break_on_match => "true"
        match => ["message", '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} \"%{DATA:s_computername}\"']
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}  %{NOTSPACE:uriQuery} "]
    }
    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
        }
    }
}
```

simplified version. I want `elasticsearch` to have a entry containing `log_timestamp`, `s_computername`, and `uriQuery`.

Using the multiline codec, it is possible to merge them if the lines were next to each other. As they're in separate files, I have not yet found a way to do this. Is it possible to merge the two using the same timestamp as a unique identifier?

Comment: You mean to show both of them in one single record in ES?

Comment: This may be able to be acheived using the [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) or [collate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-collate.html) community filter for logstash. A better solution would be simply modifying your Advanced IIS log structure, which is custom defined, to include all the data you need.